# Concatenating elements into a list in a anonymous function in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, lambda, higher-order-functions

I am new to Haskell and cannot seem to find a reason for not being able to compile this:

```
test = foldr (\x y -> y : x) [1]
```

I am not trying to achieve anything functionally for the dummy function "test".

Just that I keep getting this error code:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = [a0]
    In the first argument of `(:)', namely `y'
    In the expression: y : x
    In the first argument of `foldr', namely `(\ x y -> y : x)'
```

All I want to do is to be able to concatenate elements from a list, to form another list within an anonymous function defined in another function (in this case, defined in "test".)

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `foldr (\x y -> x : y) [1]` (or, equivalently, just `foldr (:) [1]`)?

Comment: actually i was trying to simplfy a bigger problem i have with regards to the types.

Comment: Well, the reason will probably be similar, just more complicated. If you show us more of the bigger problem, we might be able to help with that too.

Comment: @DanielFischer okay ill post it in another question. Thanks.

Comment: This is the link to the bigger problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883559/guards-and-concatiating-to-lists-in-an-anonymous-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `foldr` is

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

so if we try to use it

```
test = foldr (\x y -> y : x) [1]
```

we must have the following types:

```
b = Num n => [n]
```

since the argument for an empty input list has that type, and

```
(\x y -> y : x) :: (a -> b -> b)
                :: Num n => (a -> [n] -> [n])
```

But the lambda is `flip (:)` and thus has the type

```
(\x y -> y : x) :: [t] -> t -> [t]
```

and trying to unify that with `a -> [n] -> [n]`, we find

```
a == [t]
t == [n]
[t] == [n]
```

which implies `t == [t]`.

If you don't `flip` the cons `(:)`, it will type-check, but the function would be easier expressed as

```
test xs = xs ++ [1]
```

or, point-free

```
test = (++ [1])
```

Comment: could you elaborate more at the "since the arguement for an empty input list has that type". When you say arguement, what do you mean by that?

Comment: The second argument of `foldr` is the result for an empty input list, it has type `b`; in your example, that argument is `[1]`, and `[1] :: Num n => [n]`. Let me think how to express it better.